# Add events to Geoexplorer

Tags: geoserver, boundless-suite, geoexplorer

I need add new Controls to GeoExplorer. I seen geoexplorer.js inside OpenGeo Suite and I will want to view the coordinates of points. But If I add map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());

I see a error because the MousePosition method no exist. I seen that events as Navigation is as a Object but I don't know as do it to MousePosition

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do a custom build of GeoExplorer and add MousePosition to the build profile here: https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/blob/master/geoexplorer/buildjs.cfg

Alternatively, you should look at the Boundless SDK instead.